# Al seleccionar cancelar, cuando al usuario se le solicita el nombre, inmediatamente devuelve "null"

Tags: javascript, condiciones, function, operador, confirmar

En este código sale un error por consola donde se lee "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')" y es cuando aparece el confirm y el usuario selecciona "cancelar" en vez de "aceptar".

Según lo que entiendo no es ningún error cuando se presiona "cancelar" y no se introduce ningún nombre pues cancelar es como si no se introdujera nada y esto Javascript lo toma como "null" (null = vacío o nada). De hecho en los prompts y otros elementos funciona así cuando se escoge o se pulsa "cancelar", pero... ¿esto es así o hay alguna forma de solucionarlo?

```
let nombre = prompt("Favor ingrese su nombre");
    
    function saludar(){
        if ((nombre == null) || (nombre != confirm))
        document.getElementById("bienvenida").innerHTML ="Bienvenido/a";
        else(nombre !=null)
        document.getElementById("bienvenida").innerHTML ="Bienvenido/a " + nombre;
    }
    
    saludar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparece *null* en el texto de bienvenida porque si el usuario pulsa cancelar, este se considera como null, es decir, nulo. Si pulsa el botón *Aceptar*, el valor en la caja es "". Si dice "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')", es porque no existe ninguna etiqueta con el valor de id *bienvenida*. No se si es a lo que te refieres, pero el siguiente código realiza lo que quieres:

- Se imprime solo ese texto si el valor es nulo o estrictamente está vacío

```js
let nombre = prompt("Favor ingrese su nombre");
    
    function saludar(){
       if(!nombre || nombre === "") {
        document.getElementById("bienvenida").innerHTML = "Bienvenido/a";
       } else {
        document.getElementById("bienvenida").innerHTML = "Bienvenido/a " + nombre;
       }
    }
    
    saludar();
```

```html
<p id="bienvenida"></p>
```

Comment: Tal como añades el código, si lo ejecutas verás, que si cancelas la opción aparecerá bienbenido null, y lo que quiere es que si se cancela solo aparezca bienvenido

Comment: @PedroPicateclas ya lo he editado

Answer (score 0):

El código correcto sería como explica Programando pero quitando el confirm del if, y quitandole el parentesis del else. De la siguiente manera funciona

```js
let nombre = prompt("Favor ingrese su nombre");
    
    console.log(nombre)
    function saludar(){
        if (nombre === null) {
          document.getElementById("bienvenida").innerHTML ="Bienvenido/a"
        }else {
        document.getElementById("bienvenida").innerHTML ="Bienvenido/a " + nombre
        }
    }
    
    saludar();
```

```html
<p id="bienvenida"></p>
```